# Create template class in C++ method?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

How can I do the following, without having to include every class T in this file?:

```
// ComponentMan.h
class ComponentMan
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void CreateComponent<T>()
    {
        T* temp = new T();
    }
}
```

Basically, I want a generic class instantiater. How can I achieve this without including headers everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the other way round; you include "ComponentMan.h" everywhere you want to use it.  e.g.:

**foo.h**

```
class Foo {
    ...
};
```

**blah.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "ComponentMan.h"

void bar() {
    ComponentMan man;
    man.CreateComponent<Foo>();
}
```